# Wicket SEO: removing "?wicket:interface=..." from AjaxFallbackLinks

Tags: java, seo, wicket

I use Wicket's [AjaxFallbackLink](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/AjaxFallbackLink.html) in a number of places. This works fine for users, but it's giving us some SEO headaches.

When Google crawls one of our pages, it might be hours or days before they return and try crawling the `AjaxFallbackLinks` on that page. Of course since the links look like this:

```
http://example.com/?wicket:interface=:1869:mediaPanel:permissionsLink::IBehaviorListener:0:2
```

... the session is no longer valid by the time the crawler returns. This results in a ton of `404` errors on our site, which presumably harms our SEO.

**My question**: how can I make the Ajax links "stable" (like a `BookmarkablePageLink`) for search engines, but still retain the Ajax behavior for interactive users?

Comment: Isn't the same content available if JavaScript is turned off?

Comment: Hang on, what's the point of an `AjaxFallbackLink`, if it can be invoked in a bookmarkable fashion? Why not just use a `BookmarkablePageLink`? Sorry, I'm a bit confused as to what you want.

Comment: @biziclop I can see the usecase here. For 'normal' (= ajaxified) operation, a click on the link will replace a panel, for crawlers (= no ajax) there is a stable link (using URLcoded PageParameters) that redisplays the whole page with the panel replaced.

Comment: Yes- that is exactly my usecase- I use a series of links as "buttons" that end up replacing a panel with different content when clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Google to ignore certain URL parameters by using the URL Parameter options in Google Webmaster Tools. As of July 2011, you can even tell Google what to do in the case where changing the URL parameters has an effect on the page content (e.g. paging or sorting).

> To access the feature, log into your Google webmaster tools account,
>   click on the site you want to configure, and then choose Site
>   configuration > URL parameters. You’ll see a list of parameters Google
>   has found on the site, along with the number of URLs Google is
>   “monitoring” that contain this parameter.
>
> The default behavior is “Let Googlebot decide”. This results in Google
>   figuring out duplicates and clustering them.

- http://searchengineland.com/google-adds-url-parameter-options-to-google-webmaster-tools-86769

The question for you is whether the content of the page does change when you ignore the wicket:interface params. If it does, maybe you need to explore moving to a stateless Ajax fallback, such as the one described here:

- https://github.com/jolira/wicket-stateless